# field in IP packet may change at receiver end.

Tags: networking, ipv4, ttl

if A send ipv4 packet to B. and the packet is received without any error so which field of ipv4 packet may change at receiver end.

1)TTL

2)Checksum

3)Fragment offset

and what is the condition in which they may change.

Comment: Do your own homework.

Comment: i am sure about the 1 and 2 and knew the fragment offset is change when mtu is smaller the packet size . i don't knew whether it's change after defragmentation.